# How to Iterate though scala dataframe rows and store the column name in variables which can be used for some opertions inside for loop?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Need to understand , how to iterate through scala dataframe using for loop and do some operation inside the for loop. I can iterate using below code but i can not do any other operation like storing the column value in a variable or calling another function. Can you help with storing the column value in a variable.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
case class cls_Employee(name:String, sector:String, age:Int);
val df = Seq(cls_Employee("Andy","aaa", 20), cls_Employee("Berta","bbb", 30), cls_Employee("Joe","ccc", 40)).toDF()
df.as[cls_Employee].take(df.count.toInt).foreach(t => 
{t.name}
)
```

Comment: You have to do an action (like collect or foreach) in order to have the data available, then you can do whatever you want. As said by someone in the answers, be careful to not go in OutOfMemory, since the data you are going to collect will be in the driver memory!

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

case class Employee(name:String, sector:String, age:Int)
val df = Seq(Employee("Andy","aaa", 20), Employee("Berta","bbb", 30), Employee("Joe","ccc", 40)).toDF()

for (row <- df.as[Employee].collect()) {
  val name = row.name
  println(name)
}
```

be careful because in this case you are doing a collect and in the presence of a lot of data you might get an outofmemory from the driver

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

```
case class CLSEmployee(name: String, sector: String, age: Int)
```

```
val df = Seq(
    ("Andy", "aaa", 20),
    ("Berta", "bbb", 30),
    ("Joe", "ccc", 40)
).toDF("name", "sector", "age")
```

```
// extract data from DataFrame & store it in variable.
val names = df.as[CLSEmployee].take(df.count.toInt).map(_.name)
```

```
// for example, function
def lower(name: String): String = { name.toLowerCase}
```

```
// calling function
df.as[CLSEmployee].map(row => lower(row.name))
```